# Determine the equivalence relation on {1, 2, 3, 4}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If the relation is an equivalence relation, list the equivalence classes.

$$\{(x, y) : 4 \mid x - y\}$$

I have no clue how to solve this.

What I have tried is:

To know its an equivalence relation, it has to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

So it is reflexive as $(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)$ is valid...

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: To get curly braces to display, use `\{` and `\}`.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

- **Symmetry:** If $4\mid x-y$, there is an integer $k$ such that $x-y=4k$. And $y-x=-(x-y)$, so ... ?
- **Transitivity:** If $4\mid x-y$ and $\mid y-z$, then there are integers $k$ and $m$ such that $x-y=4k$ and $y-z=4m$. Try to use this to express $x-z$ as a multiple of $4$.